# index.html served from disk cache. Not able to update

Tags: reactjs, http, caching

I have a PWA react-app. I use service worker for caching. However i haven't mentioned index.html in my list of precaching for workbox during a build. Due to this index.html is cached in the disk cache and served from there everytime. The main..js and main..css are updated in memory cache because i am caching them in workbox precache. This is leading to index.html not updated and trying to access old main..js and main..css

My app is crashing coz of this.

1. I tried clearing the entire cache storage on chrome.
2. I set http-equiv headers for no-cache, expires 0. None of them seem to be working.

Do i have some way to mention the response headers for index.html so that it never picks up from disk cache ?